# How can i hide an element which is inside an element?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `span` element inside my `p` element. When I click the span, editable area shows up.

I want to hide the `span` in my editable `input` area.

How can i make it?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9v7kbr1g/)

HTML

```
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum.<span>&#x2710;</span></p>
<input type="text" class="editable"/>
```

JS

```
$(".editable").hide();

$("span").click(function() {
  $(".text").css("color", "red");
  var val1 = $("p").text();
  $(".editable").show().val(val1);
});

$(".editable").keyup(function() {
  var keyed = $(".editable").val();
  $(".text").text(keyed);  
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) at this context,

```
$("span").click(function() {
  //...other codes
  var val1 = $("p").contents()[0].nodeValue;
  //...other codes
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9v7kbr1g/3/)

---

Or a javascript solution using `.firstChild`

```
$("span").click(function() {
  $(".text").css("color", "red");
  var val1 = $("p")[0].firstChild.textContent;
  $(".editable").show().val(val1);
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9v7kbr1g/7/)

---

And the best option would be wrapping that required text in a span like below,

HTML:

```
<p class="text">
  <span class="textInner">Lorem ipsum.</span>
  <span class="edit">&#x2710;</span>
</p>
<input type="text" class="editable"/>
```

JS:

```
$("span.edit").click(function() {
  var $parent = $(this).closest(".text").css("color", "red");
  $parent.next(".editable").show().val($(this).prev(".textInner").text());
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9v7kbr1g/6/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you can do:

- Get the text node of p element and get text without span tag
- Set html of p tag using input field text and span html

```js
$(function(){
$(".editable").hide();

$("span").click(function() {
 $(".text").css("color", "red");
 var val1 = $('p').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
 }).text();
 $(".editable").show().val(val1);
});

$(".editable").keyup(function() {
 var keyed = $(".editable").val();
 $(".text").html(keyed + "<span>&#x2710;</span>");  
});});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum.<span>&#x2710;</span></p>
<input type="text" class="editable"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by placing the unicode pencil character in the HTML using a CSS pseudo element, so that it's ignored as part of the `text()` content of the `p`. This makes the JS much simpler and means you don't have to change it at all. Try this:

```js
$(".editable").hide();

$(".edit-trigger").click(function() {
    $(".text").css("color", "red");
    var val1 = $("p").text();
    $(".editable").show().val(val1);
});

$(".editable").keyup(function() {
    var keyed = $(".editable").val();
    $(".text").text(keyed);
});
```

```css
p.edit-trigger:after {
    content: '\2710';
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.editable {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text edit-trigger">Lorem ipsum.</p>
<input type="text" class="editable" />
```

Comment: Nice but the downside is that it makes the entire `p` element clickable

Comment: True, that's the only real down-side.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Wysihtml](http://wysihtml.com/) instead, as this does what I understand that you want. It is a fully-fledged HTML5 What You See Is (What You Get) HTML5 editor, used for an example in [Voog CMS](http://wysihtml.com/). Has all and more features you'd like.

Comment: why this may answer the question, only link answers are not future proof. try adding some more detail to your answer for future readers, for instance when the website you linked to is not reachable anymore

Answer (score 0):

use display: none in the css

```
$("span").click(function() {
  $(".text").css("display", "none"); //<--
  var val1 = $("p").text();
  $(".editable").show().val(val1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : you can clone the p element and remove span and then read text.

```
$("span").click(function() {
  $(".text").css("color", "red");
  var val1 = $("p").clone().find('span').remove().end().text();
  $(".editable").show().val(val1);
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9v7kbr1g/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this in your code:

```
$("span").click(function() {
  $(".text").css("color", "red");
  var val1 = $("p").text();
  $(".editable").show().val(val1);
  $(this).hide();//added this line to hide the span
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi instead of trying to tweak around with jQuery... you can solve the issue by simply placing the `span` outside the `paragraph` ... kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/9v7kbr1g/14/

**HTML**

```
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum.</p>
<span class="pencil">&#x2710;</span>
<div class="clear"></div>
<input type="text" class="editable"/>
```

**CSS**

```
span {
  font-size:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.editable {
  word-break:break-all;
}

p.text,.pencil{
  float:left;
}

.pencil{
  margin-top:10px;
}

.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

**jQuery (Same as yours I didnt edit anything)**

```
$(".editable").hide();

$("span").click(function() {
  $(".text").css("color", "red");
  var val1 = $("p").text();
  $(".editable").show().val(val1);
});

$(".editable").keyup(function() {
  var keyed = $(".editable").val();
  $(".text").text(keyed);  
});
```

Comment: Dude you are really so smart i mean it , really , but first read the question clearly.

Comment: Haha thx for the compliments.. I read the question and many answered your question too... I just thought let me provide a simple alternative...